# playframework seleniums intellij idea intelli sense support

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm writing selenium tests in playframework 1.2.4 using IntelliJ idea (it has some support of playframework now). Is it possible to use some syntax help for selenium tests, which is actually located in html files?

For example there is a tests (in mytest.test.html file)

```
#{selenium 'software detail renders with back-link on board'}

    openAndWait('/detail/1')

    assertVisible('//div[@id="util-panel"]//a[@id="back-link"]')

#{/selenium}
```

Of course I can use intelli-j templates/sniplets. But I would prefer syntax support.

Comment: So, the JetBrains officially released support for that, you could accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that helps with Selenium tests: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/intellij-idea-2020-1-selenium-support/

It provides XPath/CSS highlighting and completion for the most used Selenium APIs, including Geb, Selenide and ScalaTest.